# Is there any performance difference when select from subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

Is there any performance difference if I run these queries in Postgresql? Assuming that the table has many rows.

```
SELECT c.name 
FROM products as p
JOIN category as c on p.type = c.type 
WHERE c.name = 'a';

SELECT a.name 
FROM (
  SELECT c.name 
  FROM products as p
  JOIN category as c on p.type = c.type
) as a 
WHERE a.name = 'a';
```

** edited

using entity framework linq, like this,

```
context.table.FromSql("complex query from random developer").Where(a => ....)
```

would create query similar to the second query, (querying from a subquery)

In SQL Server, both will return the same execution plan but I am new to Postgresql and I don't know how to test it.

After using `explain (analyze) SELECT ...` in Postgresql as suggested, I found that the execution plan is similar. So I am assuming that both the queries would not has much different in term of performance. So, I will use the entity framework like usual without editing the complex query.

Comment: No, but why have a sub-query?

Comment: There should not be.  Postgres has a smart optimizer and will ignore the subquery.

Comment: Why not [race your horses?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @jarlh I am trying to use linq WHERE clause on a complex query ```context.something.FromSql("query written by someone else").Where(a => ...)```. And i see the generated sql query looks something like the second query. So I am wondering if it is better to add the where clause directly on the complex query.

Comment: Just keep the code simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference whatsoever.

You can easily find that out by yourself, by looking at the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze) select ...`.

Except for the aliases the plans should be identical.

Comment: . . Are you sure this is true if a non-standard index could be used for the comparison or if `category` is partitioned on `name`?  I assume they are the same, but some optimizations can be tricky.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, very sure. I have never seen a derived table with a simple query like that changing the plan or the index usage.

Comment: I ask because I'm pretty sure that BigQuery will mess up on partition pruning if subqueries start to get involved.  Partition pruning tends to be finicky in databases -- as might the use of other types of indexes (although I'm sure it is fine for b-tree indexes).